# How to add button on SharePoint allitems.aspx list view column and update list items on its click event?

Tags: sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-workflow

I want to achieve following functionality

1) Create button on SharePoint **document library** column on **allitems.aspx** view.

2) On clicking of that button document library field values should get updated.

I could create button on allitems.aspx listview using designer in **SharePoint 2010**, but could not do it in **SharePoint 2013** as there is no design view in SP2013 designer.

Which is the best way to update doc library items on column button click? Please share the detailed steps if possible.